# Linked List insertion in Beginning

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying basic creation of linked list using C. I have written the following code which is working up until first node but fails eventually on second one. I think the issue is where I am trying to display the node values in list separated by arrow(->). I think my logic is right but please correct me. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node NODE;
NODE *node1, *node2, *start, *save;

int main()
{
    node1 = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    int i = 0;
    start = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int inf;

        printf("Enter node value:");
        scanf("%d", &inf);

        node1->number = inf;
        node1->next = NULL;

        if(start == NULL)
        {
            start = node1;
            save = node1;
        }
        else
        {
            // save=start;
            // start=node1;
            // node1->next=save;
            node1->next = start;
            start = node1;
        }

        while(node1 != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ->",node1->number);
            node1 = node1->next;
        }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code!  It's hurting my eyes!

Comment: Looks like `node1` points to itself...

Comment: ok edited it. Please have another look.

Comment: Fails how?  What do you mean by "eventually"?

Comment: I removed "eventually". Sorry for Grammar mistake as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `malloc()` inside `for` loop.
Since it is outside, same memory is being used.

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy! Can't believe that was causing the error. :D

Comment: Glad that I helped you. Please up vote and accept the answer if it worked for you. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The issues are

- How you're allocating your nodes for insertion (i.e. save for one, you're not).
- How they're placed in the list once you fix the above.
- Don't cast `malloc` in C programs (read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?s=1|6.6133) for why).
- Fail to check the success of your `scanf` invoke.
- Fail to check the success of your `malloc` invoke

Before you get discouraged, things you did **correctly**:

- Did *not* mask a node pointer in a `typedef`
- Properly included a MCVE for review
- Prospected the things you may be doing wrong.

A **very** simple example of iterating three values into a linked list would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node NODE;

int main()
{
    NODE *head = NULL, *p;
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int inf;

        printf("Enter node value:");
        if (scanf("%d", &inf) == 1)
        {
            p = malloc(sizeof *p);
            if (p != NULL)
            {
                p->number = inf;
                p->next = head;
                head = p;
            }
            else
            {
                perror("Failed to allocate new node");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // failed to read data. break
            break;
        }

        // report current linked list
        printf("%d", p->number);
        for (p=p->next; p; p = p->next)
            printf(" -> %d", p->number);
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }

    // cleanup the linked list
    while (head)
    {
        p = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(p);
    }
    head = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

The values `1 2 3` are input upon being prompted:

**Output**

```
Enter node value:1
1
Enter node value:2
2 -> 1
Enter node value:3
3 -> 2 -> 1
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Vamsi, you should use `malloc` to put the nodes on the heap.  You also generally shouldn't cast the output of `malloc`, it isn't needed.  And then you could play around with making a doubly-linked list, where you also have a `prev` pointer inside your `struct`.